# Download Google Drive SDK thumbnailLink provides cached file

Tags: caching, google-drive-api

Using Google Drive SDK I retrieve the thumbnailLink property for a Google document and I then use this to download the generated image, which I cache on a file server. However, I'm seeing that I often get a thumbnail of an older version of my document, it could be a version cached by Google drive.

This thumbnail link has this form:
https://docs.google.com/...&sz=s220

You can get different thumbnail sizes based on the sz argument. The interesting thing is that I'm seeing different versions (older or newer thumbnails of my document) of the thumbnail depending on the value of the sz argument.

Is there a way to get a fresh thumbnail when a Google document has been updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does appear to be some caching going on with the thumbnail URLs, such that certain ranges of sizes are cached together. In my experience those caches do expire however, although not in a way you can completely control (as you've noted requesting a different size can sometimes cause a cache miss). The team is working on changing the thumbnail serving to a new backend that should resolve the issue, but I don't have a timeline for that change.